# how to display dynamic images came from dB and showing them in jsp?

Tags: java, image, jsp

I need to display images retrieved from DB into my JSP page, help!
//here is my jsp code line:

```html
<img src="<c:url value="/downloadimage"> 
<c:param name="id" value="${obj.id}"/>
</c:url>" alt="cant show image!" width="200px" height="200px"/>
```

//here is my controller method:

```js
@GetMapping("/downloadimage")
public void  downloadimage(@RequestParam("id") int id,HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
            
    byte[] imageBytes = autherService.getImageAsBytes(id);
            
    try {
                
        if(imageBytes != null) {
            response.setContentType(
                     servletContext.getMimeType("name.jpg"));
            response.setContentLength(imageBytes.length);
            response.getOutputStream().write(imageBytes);
        } 
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
            
}
```

//here is DAO impl class code :

```js
@Override
public byte[] getImageAsBytes(int id) {
    String sql = "SELECT image FROM picture_tbl WHERE id = ?";
    Object[] args = { id };
    Picture picture = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql,args, new PictureRowMapper());
    return picture.getImageAsBytes();
}
```

Comment: You can not define the value of `id` in `autherService.getImageAsBytes(id)` and please upload image of your `table` where image is stored

Comment: I have created two methods to retrieve data from Db, the first get the image details which have id , the id displayed in <img> tag in jsp as shown earlier, then i want the URL inside the img tag to call a mapping method to retrieve the image, and display it. and it didn't work ... thank you for commenting

Comment: Show me your `PictureRowMapper`...